# view json api from url into an html page by js

Tags: javascript, json

how to parse json from an url into html by using javascript (programmatically) and i facing an problem with this ?

api:   https://corona.ps/API/summary

Comment: The short answer is that your Javascript fetches the json response then inserts the data you care about into the DOM where you want it (The DOM is what the browser builds by interpreting the HTML) -- without more detail in your question it's hard to be more specific. Post some HTML and Javascript that you're working on, and more specifically where you're having trouble.

Comment: code pleaseeeee

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the built in JavaScript fetch() method which returns a promise. Use .then() to handle the response and .catch() to handle any errors relating to the fetch call.

Here's an example function using your api link:

```
function getData () {
    fetch("https://corona.ps/API/summary")
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(data => console.log(data)) // will log js object
     .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```